# add a tag to many td elements

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with hundreds of rows.
The table is done after converting a csv file to html table using https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-html.htm

I want a specific column of the table to contains a link, but I don't know how to add  to hundreds of  at a time.

```
<tr>
  <td>title 1</td>
  <td align="right">5.18</td>
  <td align="right">17.27</td>
  <td align="right">70</td>
  <td>www.google.com/</td>
  <td align="right">32958865536</td>
</tr>
```

the 5th td is always a link, but td don't contain  so I need a way to add the a tag to all 5th td of the table

I use vscode

Comment: To select 5th td of the rows  you can use  css selector : " table>tbody>tr td:nth-child(5) { }"

Comment: On the convertcsv.com CSV to HTML page, load your data and then convert. After that modify the template under "Create Custom Output via Template" and change the 5th td entry to include the anchor tag. Press "CSV to HTML via Template" to test.

Comment: I didn't figure out how to do it, what should I put exactly ? I mean inside  <td>{f5}</td> ?

Comment: Correct: something like <td><a href="https://{f5}">{f5}</a></td> depending on whether the URLs already start with https or not. You'll have to experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the selector you need:

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

You can select every 5th td of each table row with following script, considering `tableContent` is the id of table

```
 $('#tablecontent  td:nth-child(5n)').addClass('someClass');
```